# Circuit symbol for spectrum analyzer

Tags: symbol, spectrum-analyzer

Does anybody know what the circuit symbol for spectrum analyzer is? My internet searches for it haven't turned up anything so far. Most of the searches ended up showing the internal circuit diagram for spectrum analyzer.

Thanks.

Comment: It is similar to the one for a PC but looks more like one for a car mixed with the one for a macbook.

Comment: A spectrum analyzer is not a component that you would use in a schematic diagram, so there's no "standard symbol" for it. In a block diagram, you would just have a rectangle with the words "spectrum analyzer" in it. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: It's a rectangle with a writing "Spectrum analyzer" on it.

Comment: @Dave Tweed: Regarding your question about what I am trying to do. We are in the process of adding a 2D view to [ElectricVLab](http://electricVLab.com) in addition to the 3D view currently present. When the user switches to 2D view from 3D view, all the 3D models get replaced by their circuit symbols. While writing "Spectrum Analyzer" inside a rectangle appeared as an option to me, that makes it language specific. So, I have been wondering whether there is a pictorial symbol that does not use English words.

Comment: I don't get why this question has so many downvotes, whats wrong with it?

Comment: In that case, it would just be a picture of the screen, showing the spectrum.

Comment: It's got downvotes because a spectrum analyser isn't a component in a circuit. Asking for a circuit symbol of a spectrum analyser is like asking for a circuit symbol of a washing machine. Try this: https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRFRm21-0EvkszXf9RLovYHJl7kndFr1DSCwzVOCBpA1FNpmr0VXw

Comment: By the way, there is indeed a well recognized circuit symbol for oscilloscopes. For example, scroll down on [this page](http://electronicsclub.info/circuitsymbols.htm). So, conceptually, when there is a symbol for the oscilloscope instrument, my expectation was that there is likely to be a pictorial symbol for spectrum analyzer as well.

Comment: For that matter, ammeter and voltmeter aren't components either and like oscilloscopes, there are pictorial symbols for these instruments as well. For example, see [this page](http://electronicsclub.info/circuitsymbols.htm) or [this](http://www.circuitstoday.com/electronic-circuit-symbols). So, it seems like whether there is a circuit symbol for something is not just a matter of whether or not it is a "component". Instead, it is likely to depend on how often people have had the need for including it in their circuit diagrams.

Answer (score 1):

A spectrum analyzer is a sufficiently esoteric and rare (and expensive!) piece of equipment that there's no generally recognized symbol for it.

Make something up! You could use something similar to the oscilloscope symbol, but with a waveform showing a single peak, similar to what one might see if analyzing a slightly noisy sine wave.